# Differential Equations: Find the general solution (Eigenvalues and eigenvectors)

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the general solution of the system $$x'=\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix} x$$ where $bc > 0$.

I got to $\lambda^2 -(a+d)\lambda + ad-bc = 0$ and then I do not know how to determine what the eigenvalues from this point. A hint would be greatly appreciated. I attempted to use the quadratic equation, but I did not know what to do with the $-4bc$ under the radical.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lambda%5E2+-(a%2Bd)lambda+%2B+ad-bc+%3D+0

Comment: But that says b=0 which would make bc=0 and it needs to be bc>0

Comment: Nope, look under "Solutions."

Comment: From $bc>0$ you should be able to determine the number of real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate discriminant $D=(a+d)^2-4(ad-bc)=(a-d)^2+4bc,$

$D>0$ because $(a-d)^2 \geq 0$ (always) and $4bc>0$ (given).

Then,
$$
\lambda_{1,2}= \frac{(a+b)\pm\sqrt{D}}{2}
$$